terraform error : Entity Already Exists error (creating IAM Policy oa_aedl_xaccess_kms_policy: )
Can someone guide me how to resolve this issue.
error creating IAM Policy oa_aedl_xaccess_kms_policy: EntityAlreadyExists: A policy called oa_aedl_xaccess_kms_policy already exists. Duplicate names are not allowed.
│   status code: 409, request id: f52d0aca-6cf5-42b6-97b1-56a88942d629
i was trying to do terraform apply i am getting the above error.
